# kafka-console-consumer running in docker container stops consuming messages

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, confluent-platform

I have confluent kafka (v4.0.0) brokers and 3 zookeepers running in [docker-compose](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/tree/4.0.x/examples/kafka-cluster).  A test topic was created with 10 partitions with replication factor 3.
When a console-consumer is created w/o passing --group option (where group.id will be assigned automatically), it can continuously consume messages even after a broker is killed and the broker is back on line.

However, if I create a console-consumer with --group option ('console-group'), message consumption is stopped after a kafka broker is killed.

```
$ docker run --net=host confluentinc/cp-kafka:4.0.0 kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:19092,localhost:29092,localhost:39092 --topic starcom.status --from-beginning --group console-group
<< some messages consumed >>
<< broker got killed >> 
[2017-12-31 18:34:05,344] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-group] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
<< no message after this >>
```

Even after the broker is back on line, the consumer-group doesn't consume any further messages.

Strange thing is that there's no lag for that consumer group when I checked with kafka-consumer-groups tool.  In other words, consumer offsets are advancing for that consumer group. There's no other consumer running with the group.id, so something is wrong.

Based on logs, it seems that group had been stabilized.

```
kafka-2_1           | [2017-12-31 17:35:40,743] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Preparing to rebalance group console-group with old generation 0 (__consumer_offsets-33) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka-2_1           | [2017-12-31 17:35:43,746] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Stabilized group console-group generation 1 (__consumer_offsets-33) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka-2_1           | [2017-12-31 17:35:43,765] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Assignment received from leader for group console-group for generation 1 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka-2_1           | [2017-12-31 17:54:30,228] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Preparing to rebalance group console-group with old generation 1 (__consumer_offsets-33) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka-2_1           | [2017-12-31 17:54:31,162] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Stabilized group console-group generation 2 (__consumer_offsets-33) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka-2_1           | [2017-12-31 17:54:31,173] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Assignment received from leader for group console-group for generation 2 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka-2_1           | [2017-12-31 17:57:25,273] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Preparing to rebalance group console-group with old generation 2 (__consumer_offsets-33) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka-2_1           | [2017-12-31 17:57:28,256] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Stabilized group console-group generation 3 (__consumer_offsets-33) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka-2_1           | [2017-12-31 17:57:28,267] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Assignment received from leader for group console-group for generation 3 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka-2_1           | [2017-12-31 17:57:53,594] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Preparing to rebalance group console-group with old generation 3 (__consumer_offsets-33) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka-2_1           | [2017-12-31 17:57:55,322] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Stabilized group console-group generation 4 (__consumer_offsets-33) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka-2_1           | [2017-12-31 17:57:55,336] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Assignment received from leader for group console-group for generation 4 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka-3_1           | [2017-12-31 18:15:07,953] INFO [GroupCoordinator 3]: Preparing to rebalance group console-group-2 with old generation 0 (__consumer_offsets-22) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka-3_1           | [2017-12-31 18:15:10,987] INFO [GroupCoordinator 3]: Stabilized group console-group-2 generation 1 (__consumer_offsets-22) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka-3_1           | [2017-12-31 18:15:11,044] INFO [GroupCoordinator 3]: Assignment received from leader for group console-group-2 for generation 1 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka-2_1           | [2017-12-31 18:08:59,087] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Loading group metadata for console-group with generation 4 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka-2_1           | [2017-12-31 18:09:02,453] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Preparing to rebalance group console-group with old generation 4 (__consumer_offsets-33) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka-2_1           | [2017-12-31 18:09:03,309] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Stabilized group console-group generation 5 (__consumer_offsets-33) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka-2_1           | [2017-12-31 18:09:03,471] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Assignment received from leader for group console-group for generation 5 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka-2_1           | [2017-12-31 18:10:32,010] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Preparing to rebalance group console-group with old generation 5 (__consumer_offsets-33) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka-2_1           | [2017-12-31 18:10:34,006] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Stabilized group console-group generation 6 (__consumer_offsets-33) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka-2_1           | [2017-12-31 18:10:34,040] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Assignment received from leader for group console-group for generation 6 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka-2_1           | [2017-12-31 18:12:02,014] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Preparing to rebalance group console-group with old generation 6 (__consumer_offsets-33) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka-2_1           | [2017-12-31 18:12:09,449] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Stabilized group console-group generation 7 (__consumer_offsets-33) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka-2_1           | [2017-12-31 18:12:09,466] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Assignment received from leader for group console-group for generation 7 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka-2_1           | [2017-12-31 18:16:29,277] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Preparing to rebalance group console-group with old generation 7 (__consumer_offsets-33) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka-2_1           | [2017-12-31 18:16:31,924] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Stabilized group console-group generation 8 (__consumer_offsets-33) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka-2_1           | [2017-12-31 18:16:31,945] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Assignment received from leader for group console-group for generation 8 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka-2_1           | [2017-12-31 18:17:54,813] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Preparing to rebalance group console-group with old generation 8 (__consumer_offsets-33) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka-2_1           | [2017-12-31 18:18:01,256] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Stabilized group console-group generation 9 (__consumer_offsets-33) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka-2_1           | [2017-12-31 18:18:01,278] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Assignment received from leader for group console-group for generation 9 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka-2_1           | [2017-12-31 18:33:47,316] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Preparing to rebalance group console-group with old generation 9 (__consumer_offsets-33) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka-2_1           | [2017-12-31 18:33:49,709] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Stabilized group console-group generation 10 (__consumer_offsets-33) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka-2_1           | [2017-12-31 18:33:49,745] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Assignment received from leader for group console-group for generation 10 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka-2_1           | [2017-12-31 18:34:05,484] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Preparing to rebalance group console-group with old generation 10 (__consumer_offsets-33) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka-2_1           | [2017-12-31 18:34:07,845] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Stabilized group console-group generation 11 (__consumer_offsets-33) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka-2_1           | [2017-12-31 18:34:07,865] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Assignment received from leader for group console-group for generation 11 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka-2_1           | [2017-12-31 19:34:16,436] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Preparing to rebalance group console-group with old generation 11 (__consumer_offsets-33) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka-2_1           | [2017-12-31 19:34:18,221] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Stabilized group console-group generation 12 (__consumer_offsets-33) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka-2_1           | [2017-12-31 19:34:18,248] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Assignment received from leader for group console-group for generation 12 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
```

And topic replication happened all normally.

```
$ docker run --net=host confluentinc/cp-kafka:4.0.0 kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:22181 --topic starcom.status --describe
Topic:starcom.status    PartitionCount:10       ReplicationFactor:3     Configs:
        Topic: starcom.status   Partition: 0    Leader: 3       Replicas: 3,1,2 Isr: 2,3,1
        Topic: starcom.status   Partition: 1    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 3,2,1
        Topic: starcom.status   Partition: 2    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2,3,1 Isr: 3,2,1
        Topic: starcom.status   Partition: 3    Leader: 3       Replicas: 3,2,1 Isr: 3,2,1
        Topic: starcom.status   Partition: 4    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,3,2 Isr: 3,2,1
        Topic: starcom.status   Partition: 5    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2,1,3 Isr: 3,2,1
        Topic: starcom.status   Partition: 6    Leader: 3       Replicas: 3,1,2 Isr: 2,3,1
        Topic: starcom.status   Partition: 7    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 3,2,1
        Topic: starcom.status   Partition: 8    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2,3,1 Isr: 3,2,1
        Topic: starcom.status   Partition: 9    Leader: 3       Replicas: 3,2,1 Isr: 3,2,1

$ docker run --net=host confluentinc/cp-kafka:4.0.0 kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:22181 --topic starcom.status --describe
Topic:starcom.status    PartitionCount:10       ReplicationFactor:3     Configs:
        Topic: starcom.status   Partition: 0    Leader: 3       Replicas: 3,1,2 Isr: 2,3
        Topic: starcom.status   Partition: 1    Leader: 2       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 3,2
        Topic: starcom.status   Partition: 2    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2,3,1 Isr: 3,2
        Topic: starcom.status   Partition: 3    Leader: 3       Replicas: 3,2,1 Isr: 3,2
        Topic: starcom.status   Partition: 4    Leader: 3       Replicas: 1,3,2 Isr: 3,2
        Topic: starcom.status   Partition: 5    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2,1,3 Isr: 3,2
        Topic: starcom.status   Partition: 6    Leader: 3       Replicas: 3,1,2 Isr: 2,3
        Topic: starcom.status   Partition: 7    Leader: 2       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 3,2
        Topic: starcom.status   Partition: 8    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2,3,1 Isr: 3,2
        Topic: starcom.status   Partition: 9    Leader: 3       Replicas: 3,2,1 Isr: 3,2

$ docker run --net=host confluentinc/cp-kafka:4.0.0 kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:22181 --topic starcom.status --describe
Topic:starcom.status    PartitionCount:10       ReplicationFactor:3     Configs:
        Topic: starcom.status   Partition: 0    Leader: 3       Replicas: 3,1,2 Isr: 2,3,1
        Topic: starcom.status   Partition: 1    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 3,2,1
        Topic: starcom.status   Partition: 2    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2,3,1 Isr: 3,2,1
        Topic: starcom.status   Partition: 3    Leader: 3       Replicas: 3,2,1 Isr: 3,2,1
        Topic: starcom.status   Partition: 4    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,3,2 Isr: 3,2,1
        Topic: starcom.status   Partition: 5    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2,1,3 Isr: 3,2,1
        Topic: starcom.status   Partition: 6    Leader: 3       Replicas: 3,1,2 Isr: 2,3,1
        Topic: starcom.status   Partition: 7    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 3,2,1
        Topic: starcom.status   Partition: 8    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2,3,1 Isr: 3,2,1
        Topic: starcom.status   Partition: 9    Leader: 3       Replicas: 3,2,1 Isr: 3,2,1
```

Is this a limitation of (confluent) kafka console consumer?   Basically, I am trying to ensure that my real Java Kafka consumer(s) can survive broker downtime by running this smaller test.

Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT (year 2018!)**:

I completely recreated my docker(-compose) environment and was able to reproduce this. This time I created 'new-group' consumer group and the console consumer was throwing below error after broker restarted.  And since then, messages are not consumed.  Again, according to consumer-group tool, consumer offsets are moving forward.

```
[2018-01-01 19:18:32,935] ERROR [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=new-group] Offset commit failed on partition starcom.status-4 at offset 0: This is not the correct coordinator. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
[2018-01-01 19:18:32,936] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=new-group] Asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {starcom.status-4=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=0, metadata=''}, starcom.status-5=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=0, metadata=''}, starcom.status-6=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=2, metadata=''}} failed: Offset commit failed with a retriable exception. You should retry committing offsets. The underlying error was: This is not the correct coordinator. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
```

Comment: The console consumer is just a wrapper around the Java API, but it is not able to reestablish connection to the new partition leader? If so, seems like a network/configuration issue. If you are just killing a docker container, it's losing all associated data for that broker

Comment: Thanks for the comment.   However, as I stated above, if I don't pass --group option, the console-consumer can survive ungraceful broker outage --- which is a very good thing.    This makes me to believe that it is not  a network/configuration issue.

Comment: provided more error message above

Comment: How are you producing messages? Are you sure they are distributed to the other brokers? And does it really take 2 hours for that one topic to rebalance?

Comment: Thanks for the follow up questions.  However, I think I got to the bottom of it.  Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be a docker newbie error.

When I <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>ed on kafka-console-consumer shell, the container (group.id: "console-group") was put into detached mode.  I didn't know that until I ran the `docker ps [-n | -a]` command.   When I started another console-consumer using the same command (`docker run --net=host confluentinc/cp-kafka:4.0.0 kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:19092,localhost:29092,localhost:39092 --topic starcom.status --from-beginning --group console-group`), the consumer joined the same "console-group".     That's why subsequent messages (obviously I was producing messages with the same partitioning key) were consumed by the first consumer running in the background and gave me false impression that message was being lost.  And that's why consumer-groups command showed correct offset advancement.    After re-attaching the original consumer to foreground (`docker attach <<container-id>>`) in different window, now I see all the produced messages are consumed in two different consoles based on the partition assignment.   Everything worked as expected.   Sorry for the false-alarm but hopefully someone who runs into the same issue get some hint from this.

Comment: You probably should have used `docker run --rm`

Comment: Yes.  --rm option will certainly help cleaning up the stopping container.   However, I think the culprit was more on not providing -i and -t option.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize, if I wanted to consume a few messages, correct way to set up a kafka-console-consumer in docker environment should've been

```
docker run --net=host --rm -i -t \ 
    confluentinc/cp-kafka:4.0.0 \
      kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:19092,localhost:29092,localhost:39092 --topic foo.bar
```

Notice there are --rm, -i, -t options.  '-i and -t' are not needed if you passed --max-messages in which case the console will exit normally stopping and tearing down the container.